# Change font of my application in Xamarin Forms (all label/listview...)

Tags: listview, button, fonts, label, xamarin.forms

I would like to change my fontfamilly with custom font of my application.

In the Xamarin documentation, i can see how i can change the fontfamilly just for one label, but not for my total application !

I work with Xamarin Forms for Android and IOS !

I need to change the font for my :
-Listviews
-Buttons
-Label

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [Global Style](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/application/) to apply a change to all elements in your App.  To change the font of all Label elements, you could do this:

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Styles.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="sans-serif" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Have you got an example with Font ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. And if i want to use a custom font ? Like this : https://www.behance.net/gallery/13756975/ADAMCG-PRO-Free-Typeface

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts/#Using_a_Custom_Font

Comment: I saw this post, but it's only for one label, not for all my app

Comment: @user4071320 - yes, but you apply what it says in that post *to the style code in the answer we are commenting on*. Then in applies to all labels. For example, I have a resource dictionary entry `<OnPlatform x:Key="GothamBook" x:TypeArguments="Font" iOS="GothamHTF-Book" Android="GothamHTF-Book.otf#GothamHTF-Book" />`. [Plus the font resources in appropriate places] Then in any button/label/entry `Style`, I do `<Setter Property="Font" Value="{StaticResource GothamBook}"`.

Comment: IIRC: an **implicit** Style will not affect any **explicit** Styles. In that sense, it doesn't fully override the platform's default font.You must also add the font setter to any **explicit** styles that you want to be based on your font. One way to do so is to make a "base" explicit style (per element type; e.g. targetting `Label`) that includes your font setter, and make all your explicit styles `BasedOn` that "base" style.

Answer (score 1):

This way you can use XAML code like you intended to:

```
<Label FontFamily="Arial" Text="Hi there" />
```

**Android** You can overwrite the default Renderer for all views you need it for. Here is an example for Label. You can do the same for listview and button.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (Label), typeof (MyLabelRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class MyLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if ( !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Element.FontFamily) )
                Control.Typeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.Assets, "Fonts/" + Element.FontFamily + ".otf");
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you need to map that to the location where you embedded the custom font. In my case **Assets/Fonts/Arial.otf** (Build Action: AndroidAsset).

In **iOS** you need to add it to the Resources folder: **Resources/Arial.otf** (Build Action: BundleResource) and it should work with the XAML code above.

Comment: You don't need to do custom renderer for Android.  See my comment on Jason's answer (expand to show more comments) for how to use `OnPlatform` to define the font correctly.